# ¿Por qué se me queda en bucle el siguiente código Java?

Tags: java

He realizado el siguiente código y necesito ayuda al respecto:

```
//los '*' son centinelas para evitar tener que comprobar los límites del array
char[] tablero = {'O', 'O', 'O'};
char[] solucion = {'X', 'X', 'X'};

private Bombilla padre = null;

public Bombilla() {

}

public Bombilla(char[] t, Bombilla ref) {
    for (int i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
        tablero[i] = t[i];
    }
    padre = ref;
}

@Override
public ArrayList<Ensayable> crearCompleciones() {
    ArrayList<Ensayable> lista = new ArrayList<Ensayable>();
    Bombilla hijo;
    for (int i = 0; i < tablero.length; i++) {
        char e = tablero[i];
        switch (e) {
            case 'X':
                hijo = new Bombilla(tablero, this);
                hijo.tablero[i] = 'O';
                lista.add(hijo);
                break;

            case 'O':
                hijo = new Bombilla(tablero, this);
                hijo.tablero[i] = 'X';
                lista.add(hijo);
                break;

        }

    }

    return lista;

}
//Muestra la cadena de hijos desde la última hasta la primera

@Override
public void verSolucion() {
    verTablero();
    Bombilla ref = padre;
    while (ref != null) {
        ref.verTablero();
        ref = ref.padre;
    }

}

@Override
public boolean esMeta() {

    return tablero == solucion;

}
//No hace nada especial

@Override
public boolean condicionesPoda() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void verTablero() {

    for (int i = 0; i < tablero.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(tablero);

    }
    System.out.println();

}




public Explorador(Coleccionable c , Ensayable e){
  abierta=c;
  abierta.añadir(e);}


public void explorar(){
  //El funcionamiento es el siguiente. Mientras que abierta no esté vacía, el bucle sigue:
  //Se saca el primer elemento, si es la solución, lo mete en la lista de soluciones y continua.
  //Si no lo es, crea los hijos de ese nodo, luego determina si es un nodo que merezca la pena estudiar,
  // y si lo es, lo mete en abierta, y empieza el bucle de nuevo.

  while (!abierta.esVacia()){
      Ensayable elemento=abierta.extraer();
      elemento.verTablero();
      if(elemento.esMeta()){

         soluciones.add(elemento);
      }
      else {
        lista= elemento.crearCompleciones();
        if (lista==null){

        } else
            for(Ensayable hijo:lista){
                if (hijo.condicionesPoda()){
                    abierta.añadir(hijo);
                }
            }
      }
  }
```

}

A la hora de ejecutar el siguiente código, al mostrar las soluciones siempre se me queda en bucle de:

```
000
000
000

00X
00X
00X
```

Supongo que he fallado a la hora de crear complexiones pero no se donde se encuentra mi error, creo que se añade bien y mostrar debería mostrar todas las posibilidades posibles sin ningún problema

Quiero saber como hacer para que explore todas las posibles posibilidades y mostrar el resultado por pantalla, muchísimas gracias.

Comment: De dónde sale el char [] t?

Comment: El código está incompleto, las clases/interfaces Ensayable y Coleccionable son usadas pero no sabemos qué hacen. Sospecho que el bucle `while (!abierta.esVacia()){...` no sale porque la condición no deja de cumplirse, pero no puedo afirmarlo con seguridad